# How to make PhpStorm's main tags less bolder

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, phpstorm-2017.2

Why my PhpStorm's tags are bold just like this :

[image: sample image]

[image]

Can I make it less thicker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHPStorm 2017.2.3

Editor -> Color Scheme -> Choose a Language/Markup Style(HTML / CSS  /JS for exaple) click on the specific tag then just uncheck inherited attributes toggle/untoggle bold.

This is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this by creating your Color Schema in `Preferences -> Editor -> Color Scheme`

Try also changing the font via `Preferences -> Editor -> Font`

Comment: Please be specific with your answer :')

Comment: What do you need more? All it there. You can edit Color Schema for e.g. HTML and make tag bold or not.

Comment: Could you please show how it works like can you use cloudapp ?

Comment: No one is going to take time out to record a video when Damian literally told you EXACTLY where it is in the menu. Hell, you don't even have to browse the menu....just double-shift and type "Font" and the font settings will be in the list.

Comment: @DamianDziaduch, man I just found out that there are repositories in php storm and it's really awesome,and I don't have to think too much about configuring alot